# Woocommerce issue on set programmatically sale price product

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I'm writing a script for an e-commerce with Woocommerce who read a csv and set new price/sale price on product.
The variable below are an example.

With this code I'm able to set price and sale price on product, but when the sale data is expired, the price don't return to regular price.

```
$price = '40';
$sale_price = array();
$sale_price[1] = '20';
$sale_price[2] = '2020-02-10';
$sale_price[3] = '2020-02-11';

update_post_meta( $product_id, '_price', $price );
update_post_meta( $product_id, '_regular_price', $price);

if( !empty($sale_price) ){
    update_post_meta( $product_id, '_price', $sale_price[1] );
    update_post_meta( $product_id, '_sale_price', $sale_price[1] );
    update_post_meta( $product_id, '_sale_price_dates_from', $sale_price[2] );
    update_post_meta( $product_id, '_sale_price_dates_to', $sale_price[3] );
}
```

if I don't set the '_price' post_meta I can't see the regular price or the sale price.

Comment: Because you're using date for `_sale_price_dates_from` & `_sale_price_dates_to` dates because that must be `timestamp` not direct date so update with `timestamp` and check that

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. The data_from and data_to work fine because i see the label "Offer"  who disappear when the sale data is expired

Comment: WooCommerce has an API for updating products you should use it and not directly update the post meta. Using the API ensures that all related data is consistent. In particular, WooCommerce maintains caches for prices and if you directly update a price in the database WooCommerce will not know the cache entry is now invalid and must be refreshed.

Comment: You can read about "Product Data Lookup Tables" at https://woocommerce.wordpress.com/2019/04/01/performance-improvements-in-3-6/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should do it this way:

```
$product = wc_get_product($product_id);

$price = '40';
$sale_price = array();
$sale_price[0] = '20';
$sale_price[1] = date( 'Y-m-d 00:00:00', strtotime('2020-02-10'));
$sale_price[2] = date( 'Y-m-d 23:59:59', strtotime('2020-02-11'));

if ( !is_wp_error( $product ) ) {
    $product->set_price( $price );
    $product->set_regular_price( $price );

    if( !empty($sale_price) ){
        $product->set_price( $sale_price[0] );
        $product->set_sale_price( $sale_price[0] );
        $product->set_date_on_sale_from( $sale_price[1] );
        $product->set_date_on_sale_to( $sale_price[2] );
    }

    $product->save(); // save the product
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer! 
This is what i was trying to do and seems to work fine! Now i'm tring to set this inside a timed task. Hope work with no problem!

Answer (score 0):

Please try below code that might help you

```
$price = '40';
$sale_price = array();
$sale_price[1] = '20';
$sale_price[2] = strtotime('2020-02-10');
$sale_price[3] = strtotime('2020-02-11');

update_post_meta( $product_id, '_price', $price );
update_post_meta( $product_id, '_regular_price', $price);

if( !empty($sale_price) ){
    update_post_meta( $product_id, '_price', $sale_price[1] );
    update_post_meta( $product_id, '_sale_price', $sale_price[1] );
    update_post_meta( $product_id, '_sale_price_dates_from', $sale_price[2] );
    update_post_meta( $product_id, '_sale_price_dates_to', $sale_price[3] );
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. The data_from and data_to work fine because i see the label "Offer" who disappear when the sale data is expired

Comment: No sorry. The data_from and data_to work fine without strtotime

Comment: When you try that thing from CMS and check the value which is storing to database by woocommerce then you will understand - Check this values - http://prntscr.com/r02u9j even if you check woocommerce code then also you can see this that they are using `strtotime` - http://prntscr.com/r02v8m

Comment: Thanks for the answer. We got a solution, see other post, by update meta with CRUD instead of update_post_meta

Comment: Yes that's the proper solution but I just tried to fix within your code :)

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to clear the transient cache.

PUT /wp-json/wc/v3/system_status/tools/clear_transients